# why is my if statement not comparing list items

Tags: python, loops, comparison, nested

```
    alphabet =["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
def decoder(input):
    inputlist = list(input)
    inputlength = len(input)
    alphabetlength = len(alphabet)
    result = "Decoded Sentence: "
    for x in range(inputlength):
        for y in range(alphabetlength):
            if inputlist[x] is alphabet[y]:
                print ("hi")
                if y == 24:
                    result += "a"
                if y == 25:
                    result += "b"
                else:
                    result += alphabet[y+2]
            if inputlist[x] is "(":
                result += "("
            if inputlist[x] is ")":
                result += ")"
            if inputlist[x] is ".":
                result += "."
            if inputlist[x] is " ":
                result += " "
    return result
```

My code is supposed to increment a sentence's alphabets by 2. ex: a->c, l->n
I put the print("hi") statement to check if the if-statement was ever evaluated to be true but it never does. Can someone please tell me why?

Comment: **`is`** is used for identity check not equality, though that might not be the only issue.

Comment: Just to expand on the above, is checks if they two things are the same object and location in memory. You want to user equality "==" not is.

Comment: Fyi, instead of doing a massive alphabet list, `import string` and then define alphabet as `list(string.lowercase)`.

Comment: @user2080262: Or, even better, just use `string.lowercase` directly instead of making a list out of it; he doesn't actually need a list, just an iterable, and a str already works fine.

Comment: @abarnert I suppose. I was always taught to work with lists for efficiency and format it as an `str` when outputting, with positioning and indexing etc.

Comment: @user2080262: "work with lists for efficiency" is a really bad idea in general. There are a few special cases where it makes sense (e.g., if you need to mutate things you need a list; if you're going to join up a whole bunch of strings it's better to `''.join` at the end than to string-append as you go; etc.), but in general it's nonsense. If you want an immutable iterable of characters, a string is at least as good as a list, often better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`is` checks object *identity*. Since you appear to be testing whether two strings have the same value (not are the same *object*), you would be better served by `==`. For example:

```
if inputlist[x] == alphabet[y]
```

You can make the same update for your other `if` statements as well.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `is` compares identity and not equality of strings. Two short strings that are equal *may* be identical due to some string interning CPython does, but you generally should not build on this behavior. Instead, use `==` to compare the *equality* of strings.

Note, that you can do this a lot better using [`str.translate`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate), with a map created by [`str.maketrans`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans):

```
>>> table = str.maketrans('abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwxyz', 'cdefghijklmopqrstuvwxyzab')
>>> 'hello world'.translate(table)
'jgooq yqtof'
```

You can further use [`string.ascii_lowercase`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_lowercase) so you don’t need to type the alphabet yourself; or use [`string.ascii_letters`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_letters) for lower and upper case characters:

```
>>> table = str.maketrans(string.ascii_letters, string.ascii_letters[2:] + string.ascii_letters[:2])
>>> 'Hello World (This works!)'.translate(table)
'Jgnnq Yqtnf (Vjku yqtmu!)'
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides of the `is` thin, you have another problem in your code:

As soon as `y == 24`, it will break: First, `a` will be added and then `alphabet[26]` - which results in an error.

So change your logic to

```
for inp in inputlist:
    if inp in "(). ":
        result += inp
    else: # very important
        for y in range(alphabetlength):
            if inp == alphabet[y]:
                if y == 24:
                    result += "a"
                elif y == 25: # elif instead of if!
                    result += "b"
                else:
                    result += alphabet[y+2]
```

This can even improved further:

If you make `alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'`, you can do

```
for inp in inputlist:
    if inp in "(). ":
        result += inp
    else: # very important
        idx = alphabet.find(inp)
        if idx >= 0: # found
            result += alphabet[(idx + 2) % len(alphabet)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help clear up the "is" keyword. "is" checks the object identity, not the value.

```
var_1 = ('a', 'b')
var_2 = ('a', 'b') # same content, but different object
var_3 = var_1 # same object
n = lambda v: ' ' if v else ' not '
print('{0} has{2}the same value as {1}'.format('var_1', 'var_2', n(var_1 == var_2)))
print('{0} has{2}the same value as {1}'.format('var_2', 'var_3', n(var_2 == var_3)))
print('{0} has{2}the same value as {1}'.format('var_3', 'var_1', n(var_3 == var_1)))
print('{0} is{2}the same object as {1}'.format('var_1', 'var_2', n(var_1 is var_2)))
print('{0} is{2}the same object as {1}'.format('var_2', 'var_3', n(var_2 is var_3)))
print('{0} is{2}the same object as {1}'.format('var_3', 'var_1', n(var_3 is var_1)))
```

Output:

```
var_1 has the same value as var_2
var_2 has the same value as var_3
var_3 has the same value as var_1
var_1 is not the same object as var_2
var_2 is not the same object as var_3
var_3 is the same object as var_1
```

So, all three have the same value, but only 1 and 3 are identical.

Comment: No, [`is`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#is) does _not_ check the memory address; it checks object identity. The CPython implementation happens to do that by comparing two C pointers to see if they point to the same address, but other implementations like Jython and PyPy don't (and, in fact, _couldn't_, because they're written in languages that don't have pointers or addresses).

Comment: Great clarification. I didn't think about Jython or PyPy.

Comment: @JeremyGranger So why don't you correct your answer? It might get you rid of that -1 or even gain some +1...

Comment: Just done it for you so that the answer is a good one now. @abarnert, If you was the downvoter, you might reconsider removing it. If not, not...